# Unable to create shapes using snap svg

Tags: snap.svg

Unable to load snap svg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/snap.svg.js"></script>
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/prism.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/prism.css">
        <script>
            var s = Snap("#svg");
            var circle = s.circle(90, 120, 80);
            var square = s.rect(210, 40, 160, 160);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="svg"></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tried with above sample code using netbeans and when I run the program, it displays nothing

Checked the console it says: uncaught type error: cannot read property 'circle' of null

Comment: I'm guessing its that you are running the script before the html has loaded (so it doesn't know about the svg element, as you have this after the script), so either put the script higher up, or better run the script after the page has loaded.

Comment: tried inside head section and also after body section but still not working. still the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wait until the page has finished loading...try window.onload

```
window.onload = function() {
        var s = Snap("#svg");
        var circle = s.circle(90, 120, 80);
        var square = s.rect(210, 40, 160, 160);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m88oovzz/)